# Datatable get column value gives only first 10 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Am trying to get the values of the column 1.

As the datatable docs suggested i tried,

```
 var data = table.column( 0 ).data();
```

Table configuration:

```
var datatable = table.dataTable({
            "scrollX" : "100%",
            "scrollY" : "600px",
            "scrollCollapse" : true,
            "paging" : true,
            "searching" : true,
            "ordering" :  true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: dataUrl,
                type: 'POST'
            },
            "order": [ 1, 'asc' ],
            "columns" : columns
        });
```

Since the table is with paging, it has only the values of the current page. Only the first 10 rows.

Is there any way to get all the rows of a particular column?

Comment: Can we see your table configuration?

Comment: I think this cannot be done in client side. so again am sending an ajax call to get the all the values of the column. From javascript to java to db, to get the resultset. Am not sure this is the right way or an workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "iDisplayLength": number of rows

your table will be:

```
var datatable = table.dataTable({
            "scrollX" : "100%",
            "scrollY" : "600px",
            "iDisplayLength": 20, // 20 is just an example
            "scrollCollapse" : true,
            "paging" : true,
            "searching" : true,
            "ordering" :  true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: dataUrl,
                type: 'POST'
            },
            "order": [ 1, 'asc' ],
            "columns" : columns
        });
```